# sendmail seems to be send mail but never receive

Tags: php, email, debian, sendmail

I am trying to send e-mails by sendmail over command line and with PHP with my home server. The problem I am facing is the mail is never received into my mailbox. I tried different accounts but I never received.

Port 25 is open, below I post the mail.log output:

```
Mar 24 15:40:00 FreshServer sendmail[16579]: s2OEe0Pq016579: from=www-data, size=111, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201403241440.s2OEe0Pq016579@FreshServer.lan>, relay=www-data@localhost
Mar 24 15:40:00 FreshServer sm-mta[16580]: s2OEe0bO016580: from=<www-data@FreshServer.lan>, size=380, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201403241440.s2OEe0Pq016579@FreshServer.lan>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Mar 24 15:40:00 FreshServer sendmail[16579]: s2OEe0Pq016579: to=n.xxxxx@xxxxx.nl, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30111, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s2OEe0bO016580 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar 24 15:40:13 FreshServer sm-mta[16576]: s2OEdUaT016574: to=<n.xxxxxx@xxxxx.nl>, ctladdr=<www-data@FreshServer.lan> (33/33), delay=00:00:43, xdelay=00:00:43, mailer=esmtp, pri=120380, relay=xxxxx.nl. [85.17.241.91], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with xxxxx.nl.
```

Regards,

Nick

Comment: Did you check in the SPAM

Comment: It's not in spam either

Answer (score 0):

The log states quite clearly that the connection timed out. The message is still in your local mail queue (unless you omitted relevant later log entries). The remote system is down, or dislikes you, or the firewall is less permissive than you thought.